# How to automatically copy artefacts from Jenkins job into given network drive?

Tags: jenkins

I'd like the files generated by Jenkins script to be automatically copied into a given directory on the local network.

Is there a plugin or script for doing that ?

Comment: How is that "directory" accessible? Via NFS, SMB, some S3-compatible API, ...? Mounted on the Jenkins Master?

Comment: The directory is on a shared server, on the same local network as the Jenkins server

Answer (score 0):

In my case it worked by using SCP in a build step "Execute shell". The remote server needs to be accessible via ssh.

If your artifacts are the result of a maven build, maybe a Nexus Repository Manager is what you are looking for. A simple `mvn deploy` would do the job.